# Api-platform, filtering collection result based on JWT identified user on a ManyToMany relational entity

Tags: symfony, jwt, query-builder, api-platform.com

I'm using Symfony + api-platform in their latest versions as of today.

I've got a User Entity and a Team entity which are related through a ManyToMany ORM relation.
A User can have several Teams a Team can have several Users, the Team "owns" the relation.

Once my user is logged in through a JWT Token, I would like the endpoint GET /teams to only send back the Teams in which the identified User is part of.

Here is my User entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Put;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Patch;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Delete;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(operations: [
    new Get(),
    new GetCollection()

])]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?string $password = null;
    
    /** @var book[] Available reviews for this book. */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Book::class, mappedBy: 'user', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    public iterable $books;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Team::class, inversedBy: 'users')]
    private Collection $teams;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->teams = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    /**
     * Méthode getUsername qui permet de retourner le champ qui est utilisé pour l'authentification.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername(): string {
        return $this->getUserIdentifier();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Team>
     */
    public function getTeams(): Collection
    {
        return $this->teams;
    }

    public function addTeam(Team $team): self
    {
        if (!$this->teams->contains($team)) {
            $this->teams->add($team);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTeam(Team $team): self
    {
        $this->teams->removeElement($team);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Here is my Team Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\TeamRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\User;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: TeamRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(security: "is_granted('ROLE_USER')")]

class Team
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: User::class, mappedBy: 'teams')]
    private Collection $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, User>
     */
    public function getUsers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user): self
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users->add($user);
            $user->addTeam($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user): self
    {
        if ($this->users->removeElement($user)) {
            $user->removeTeam($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Here is my CurrentUserExtension Class that filters result based on the current user :

```
<?php
// api/src/Doctrine/CurrentUserExtension.php

namespace App\Doctrine;

use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Extension\QueryCollectionExtensionInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Extension\QueryItemExtensionInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use App\Entity\Book;
use App\Entity\Team;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

final class CurrentUserExtension implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface, QueryItemExtensionInterface
{
    private $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function applyToCollection(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, Operation $operation = null, array $context = []): void
    {
        $this->addWhere($queryBuilder, $resourceClass);
    }

    public function applyToItem(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, array $identifiers, Operation $operation = null, array $context = []): void
    {
        $this->addWhere($queryBuilder, $resourceClass);
    }

    private function addWhere(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, string $resourceClass): void
    {

        if ((Book::class !== $resourceClass && Team::class !== $resourceClass) || $this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') || null === $user = $this->security->getUser()) {
            return;
        }
        
        $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
        if (Team::class == $resourceClass){
            $queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf('%s.users = :current_user', $rootAlias));
            //trigger_error($queryBuilder);
        }
        $queryBuilder->setParameter('current_user', $user->getId());
    }
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work because of the nature of the relation existing between the two tables. I also tried to use the query builder to use leftjoin and join the user_team table. But since the user_team table is not an Entity it failed.

Here is an SQL equivalent of what I would like to get as a result :

```
select * from team t
left join user_team ut on ut.team_id = t.id
where user_id = :current_user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just check if your user is `IN` or `MEMBER OF` one of your team **$users**.

Your query was close, try updating it with:

```
private function addWhere(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, string $resourceClass): void
    {

        if ((Book::class !== $resourceClass && Team::class !== $resourceClass) || $this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') || null === $user = $this->security->getUser()) {
            return;
        }
        
        $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
        if (Team::class == $resourceClass){
            $queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf(':current_user MEMBER OF %s.users', $rootAlias));
            $queryBuilder->setParameter('current_user', $user);
        }
        
    }
```

You could either use `MEMBER OF` or `IN` but in a manyToMany it's usually easier to use `MEMBER OF`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dylan. This is so abstract I need to learn more about the query builder, to me it was just a way to build SQL wuery but the syntax is way different to link entities, I would have never thought of  MEMBER OF.